# OutOfMemoryError at setImageResource() on Marshmallow

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an `ImageView` that is 797x800 when downloaded and placed into my project. However, it fits into an ImageView on my Activity that spans the width of the screen and roughly half of the height. I am using a GitHub library called `PhotoView` ([com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)) so the image can be zoomed with a pinch gesture, but the crash was occurring even before I switched to this library and just used a normal `ImageView`.

Upon pressing a button, a method is called that randomly generates a string in a `TextView`, and after 50 calls using a Handler (every 50 milliseconds), it lands on a final string and selects the image accordingly. When you click the button again, it resets the ImageView to the original, and repeats the cycle. There are 30 images within a switch statement to choose from, and the crash is occurring at `setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name_here)`.

My question is, what are my options to properly allocate enough memory for older phones to handle this? Should I just resize the image before placing it in my project? The crash report does not occur with Android versions > 6.0.

My stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream (BitmapFactory.java:856)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream (BitmapFactory.java:675)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream (Drawable.java:2228)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:4215)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:4089)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:2005)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1987)
  at android.content.Context.getDrawable (Context.java:464)
  at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri (ImageView.java:827)
  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource (ImageView.java:434)
  at com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView.setImageResource (PhotoView.java:111)
  at com.company_name.my_app_name.MainActivity.getMarker (MainActivity.java:355)
  at com.company_name.my_app_name.MainActivity.access$100 (MainActivity.java:37)
  at com.company_name.my_app_name.MainActivity$4$2.run (MainActivity.java:226)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7237)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The getMarker() method where it is occurring:

```
private void getMarker(String text) {
    switch (text) {
        case "Image 1":
            photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name1); 
            break;
        case "Image 2":
            photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name_2);
            break;
        case "Image 3":
            photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name_3);
            break;
        case "Image 4":
            photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name_4);
            break;
        case "Image 5":
            photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name_5);
            break;
//25 more switch cases follow
```

I tried a temporary fix with

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in my Manifest to no avail. I did not want that to be a permanent solution anyway.

Comment: In which drawable directories do you have your five drawable resources? Just `res/drawable/`? Just `res/drawable-anydpi/`? Several in `res/drawable-.../` directories for specific densities (e.g., `-xhdpi`)? Something else?

Comment: There's a option to downsample the image for other phones, or add alternative images into drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

Comment: All of these images are in /res/drawable/

Comment: @CommonsWare I shortened my code above for the sake of brevity. There are actually 30 images.

Answer (score 3):

> All of these images are in /res/drawable/

Move them into `res/drawable-anydpi/`. `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. Most Android devices have higher-density screens, and so Android is going to up-sample your image by quite a bit, causing them to take up quite a bit more memory.

Comment: Sadly this made the images one giant blur on all of my emulators.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce: I am not certain how that would happen. Make sure that you do not have other copies of those drawables in other resource directories.

Comment: No duplicates were present. I just moved them rather than copying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recycle older bitmaps.
First create a bitmap from the resource, and then set this bitmap to imageView. After that, recycle the old bitmap.

```
Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
Bitmap oldBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
oldBitmap.recycle();
```